# What do we know?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to ask what do we know? Since the first person, plural includes the speaker, it follows that the person already knows the answer.

Comment: It would be quite possible for the chairman to ask *What do we know?* in a board meeting, for example, when he himself knows very few of the things his directors are about to say (each of whom may be the only person in the meeting who knew the things he was going to say). But if this is about English language at all, it's something for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is a matter of _shared_ knowledge. If the speaker remains silent, everyone knows whatever they know or not. Once spoken, there is an invitation to pool the known knowledge.

Comment: Armando, do you speak another language than English? Is the sentence possible in that language? I don’t find this question to be about English but about reasoning, rhetoric, and/or the definition of *know*.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, but generally yes.

The "we" usually refers to some group that all of the people involved are a part of - e.g. an engineering team, parties at a business meeting, all of the people present in the classroom (I can imagine a professor often using "what do we know" before expanding some on something from before), mankind...

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no requirement in grammar, usage, or logic, that the speaker must not know the answer to a question when they ask it: look up [Rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).

Secondly, just because *I* is part of *we* does not mean that because *I* know something, therefore *we* must know it. If we *all* know something, then necessarily, each of us must know it; but language generally is not so logical, so we may say that *we* know something when only some of us know it.

Answer (score 1):

*we* does not always include the speaker specifically. One of the [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/we) of *we* is

> 1.2 People in general.

In the context of a small group of people, it can refer to the members of that group in general.

And since generalizations often have exceptions, what's true for the group is not necesssarily true for the speaker, even though he's a member of the group.

Furthermore, this specific question is not usually treated literally. It's interpreted as a request for members of the group to share their knowledge. You can think of it as short for "What does each of us know?"

And as mentioned in another answer, it's also sometimes used rhetorically, as in a lecture. Sometimes a speaker will introduce a concept with a question that prompts it, then proceed to answer that question.